# “assignment from incompatible pointer type” Lenguaje C

Tags: c, punteros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    struct elemento* siguiente;
    char* nombre;
}elemento;

elemento* ultimo = NULL;

void push(elemento* _elemento){
    _elemento->siguiente = NULL;
    if(ultimo == NULL){
        ultimo = _elemento;
    }else{
        _elemento -> siguiente = ultimo;
        ultimo = _elemento;
    }
}

elemento* pop(){
    if(ultimo == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    elemento* elemento_retorno = ultimo;
    ultimo = elemento_retorno -> siguiente;
    return elemento_retorno;
}
```

Claro no es el código completo porque el int main no está implementado, pero según lo errores están en:

```
_elemento -> siguiente = ultimo;
```

y en:

```
ultimo = elemento_retorno -> siguiente;
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro, bienvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo pasar por [ask] para ver como realizar una buena pregunta y que así tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Está mal visto poner solo el código, la gente que trate de ayudarte no tiene por qué descifrar que tratas de hacer. Considera editar tu pregunta añadiendo una explicación más detallada sobre lo que tratas de hacer y el problema que tienes.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es sencillo de resolver:

```
typedef struct elemento { // <-- PON el nombre ahí
    struct elemento* siguiente;
    char* nombre;
} elemento;
```

Es debido a que, en C, las `struct` **no son equivalentes** a los `typedef`. Cada cosa tiene un *espacio de nombre* distinto, y el compilador las trata, efectivamente, como **cosas distintas**.

> struct elemento* siguiente; // <-- puntero a `struct elemento`.
>   elemento* ultimo = NULL; // <-- puntero a `typedef elemento`.